# React - Lock side navbar from scrolling with hamburger menu

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar, hamburger-menu

React - Using a sidenav bar on my site, with a hamburger menu to collapse everything when not in use and giving me more screen space. Works great until the data on my page needs to scroll, in which the sidebar doesn't scroll with it. I can add position fixed, but then I have to define a left margin on my body and this changes based on the hamburger menu. Looks good when closed, but when open it is writing over my data instead of pushing it over.

Sidebar.js

```
return 
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100vh', overflow: 'hidden', position: 'fixed' }}>
    ...
```

Home.js

```
return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <Sidebar />
        {loading ?
            <h1>Loading</h1>
            :
            <div style={{ display: 'block', width: '100%', marginLeft: '80px' }}>
                ...
```

How can I make it where my sidebar doesn't scroll with the body, always taking up 100% height but also the body moves dynamically with the hamburger button? Thanks